# How to round a number up and add numeric punctuation

Tags: javascript, jquery, numbers

I've got the following pen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LVLzvR

I cant quite figure out how to round the number up so you don't break the punctuation. I need to round the number up as I don't want to see a value like 33,333.,333

```
 //ADDS PUNCTUATION EVERY THREE CHARACTERS
  $('input.numericpunctuation').keyup(function(event){

      var oNum= $(this).val(); // USE THIS NUMBER FOR CALCULATION

      var num = oNum.replace(/,/gi, "").split("").reverse().join("");

      var num2 = RemoveRougeChar(num.replace(/(.{3})/g,"$1,").split("").reverse().join(""));

      console.log(num2);
      console.log(oNum);

      // the following line has been simplified. Revision history contains original.
      $(this).val(num2);
  });

function RemoveRougeChar(convertString){


    if(convertString.substring(0,1) == ","){

        return convertString.substring(1, convertString.length)            

    }
    return convertString;

}
```

Example input event:
If I input 5555, is expect to see (and do see) 5,555. However if I add 5555.55 I get 5,555,.55. Ideally id like to round the number up removing the decimal.

Comment: rouge != rogue. One means red, the other is stray.

Comment: I don't understand the problem. Can you please add sample inputs and current and expected outputs for those inputs? Also, note that it will be extremely frustrating to edit anything in that form if the text keeps changing as you edit it

Comment: This doesn't have much bearing on the functionality but thanks for the spell check.

Comment: If I input 5555, is expect to see 5,555. However if I add 5555.55 I get 5,555,.55. Ideally if like to round the number up removing the decimal.

Comment: Is using a library like [numerals](http://numeraljs.com/) an option ?

Comment: Did you try adding more regex and string reversions?

Comment: RegEx might do it but I don't *really* understand them. #workofthedevil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem isn't just with decimals, you will get the wrong formatting also by entering non digits, e.g., clicking `King Kong` will result in `Kin,g K,ong`. So, what you probably want is to filter out non-digits, which can be done by changing the line `var oNum= $(this).val();` to:

```
var oNum= $(this).val().match(/\d/g).join('');
```

The value inside the `match` function is a RegEx object - if you never used it before then congratulations!

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I really appreciate your time. It's *almost* there. If I type 10000.33 I get 10,00033. Id like to lose the decimal numbers completely so they don't skew the numbers. Any thoughts?

Comment: Are you sure? I tried in your Pen the code posted in the question, edited with my suggestion, and it works perfectly, can you re-check?

Comment: ok. yes I see what you mean. I bashed in 5555.333 and saw 5,555,333. But I kept typing after the decimal point. Yes you are correct this works. Thanks very much.